# How to know which component is being updated while refreshing using selector in primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to know which component is being refreshed when we use prime faces selectors in 
`p:ajax` is used.

For example in the snippet:

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeViewBackingBean.root}" var="item" >
    <p:treeNode type="Type One"  >
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <p:selectOneMenu >
                    <p:ajax 
                        update="@this:@parent:@parent:@parent:@parent"  
                        listener="#{treeViewBackingBean.onChange}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

the update refers to `p:tree` or `p:treeNode`?

Is there a way to refresh only `p:treeNode`?

Answer (score 1):

To refresh only `treeNode` tag you need to do like this.

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeViewBackingBean.root}" var="item" >
    <p:treeNode type="Type One" id="treeNodeId">
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <p:selectOneMenu >
                    <p:ajax 
                        update="@this,treeNodeId" 
                        listener="#{treeViewBackingBean.onChange}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

This will update `treeNode` tag.